# Is this the right Representation of String and StringBuffer Program in Memory?

Tags: java, memory-management, heap-memory, stack-memory

package String;

//Over View: String and String Buffer Representation in Memmory

public class Strings   {

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    String s=new String("Hello");
    String t=new String("Hello");


    StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer("He");

    StringBuffer tb=sb;

    String s1="Hello";
    String t1="Hello";

    sb.append("llo");
    tb.append(" goodbye!");
    s.concat("goodbye!");
    t=s.concat("goodbye!");


}
```

}

**Memory Representation**
[image]

Comment: sb and tb reference the same StringBuffer, so changing one also changes the other. 
`s.concat("...")` returns a new concatened String and returns it. The concatenated String will be "lost" if not assigned or used. 

String and StringBuffer are different: String is immutable (=unchangeable), while StringBuffer is mutable (=changeable).

Comment: @MarkusKull And what about append?

Comment: @MarkusKull What if make a String using "new " key word and without "new".Does both have same reference or both point to same object?

Comment: `append` changes the mutable StringBuffer. 

A String created with `new` is always a distinct object - but this doesnt matter because a String is immutable and cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1):

No. The string literals are pooled, and so occur only once each.

Answer (score -1):

yes this is the right representation in collection map key concept String used in key value thatswhy sun is given string g as a immutable object and thatswhy in string class equals and hashCode methods are overidden methods but in stringBuffer class those methods are not overidden methods